# Find the width/right coordinates of a TextBlock with dynamic text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a textblock with the user's name and right at the end of the string, an image to click and edit the name.

Since I can't control the name's length and I want it to follow the input string to the last character, I need to figure the width or the right border point of the text block.

I've tried Width (NaN) and ActualWidth (always 0) after setting the Text property, but it didn't work (tried UpdateLayout() as well).

The text is left aligned to another element so I can't right-align it.

How can I get the position of the right most part of the textblock with a dynamically input text in either code or XAML?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need to find coordinates. But generally, NaN or 0 would mean the size is set by the parent container (a dependency property)

Comment: I am not sure what you have going on but it sounds like you are trying to manage the layout in code. This is not the best approach, usually.  A `StackPanel` with the `Orientation=Horizontal` will, most likely, be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActualWidth property to get the width of TextBlock. But right after setting Text, the ActualWidth will not be updated immediately. One solution is to listen changes on ActualWidth of that TextBlock, and you will get the right value whenever it's changed

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.ActualWidthProperty, typeof(TextBlock))
            .AddValueChanged(textBlock1, (s, e) =>
        {
            var yourExpecedWidth = textBlock1.ActualWidth;
        });

    }
```